# Develop an sdk in android

Tags: android

Would like to develop an sdk in android for our client ,so need help regarding coding standards and practices that needs to be followed for it.
Please share your valuable comments.

Answer (score -1):

As per the @user370305 comment, to create a native app you need to use Java. The best support software is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Using Eclipse you can install the Android simulator which is very useful as you can test against all different Android firmwares.

When developing you need to take into account the many different screen sizes and resolutions, orientation etc.

Finally, if you like you can use something like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to develop in HTML 5, CSS & JavaScript.

Hope this is what you were after.